# Laravel inserting data based on one to one relationship

Tags: php, laravel

`User` and `Address` are in one to one relationship.

`addresses` table has `user_id` field which associates it with a user.

Data can be inserted as below:

```
$user = App\User::find($id);
$address = new Address(['name'=>'221B Baker Street']);
$user->address()->save($address);
```

Here an associative array with column name from `addresses` table is passed to `Address()` constructor. But in Address.php model, there is no constructor defined for that. How does laravel handle this ?

OR if we do it the object way, like below:
where are the `setter` and `getter` methods for these ?

```
$user = App\User::find($id);
$address = new Address();
$address->name = '221B Baker Street';
$user->address()->save($address);
```

Is this a form of data abstraction ?

Comment: check out `Model.php` in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each model extends the `Model.php` from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent` which has the magic methods `__get()` and `__set()`. This is how the framework knows to dynamically set the attributes when using the object way.

As for the array given to constructor, in the abstract Model class there is method `fill()` which is called from the constructor and this way the model gets hydrated from constructor.